# How to refer a resource which is already created in ARM template?

Tags: json, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to create alerts for my cosmosdb account using arm template, the cosmosdb is already created, so Im not able use dependsOn to refer the rosurce.

```
"resources": [
  {

          "type": "microsoft.insights/alertrules",
          "name": "[parameters('alertrules_alert_name')]",
          "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
          "location": "southcentralus",

          "scale": null,
          "properties": {
              "name": "[parameters('alertrules_alert_name')]",
              "description": null,
              "isEnabled": true,
              "condition": {
                  "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.ThresholdRuleCondition",
                  "dataSource": {
                      "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleMetricDataSource",
                      "resourceUri": "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', parameters('databaseAccounts_cosmosaccount_name_1'))]",
                      "metricNamespace": null,
                      "metricName": "Http 401"
                  },
                  "operator": "GreaterThan",
                  "threshold": 1,
                  "windowSize": "PT30M"
              },
              "action": null
          }
  }
],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

Comment: you dont have use the dependson, dependson is here for resource creation dependencies. if the resource is already created, it is fine

Comment: I've tried executing the ARM template its giving me an error  "code": "UnsupportedRequestContent",                           
 "message": "Request content is not well formed or supported."

Comment: I've solved the problem by adding actions, if you give actions as null it is not executing.

Answer (score 0):

Please review the following documentation to enable *(Classic) Alerts* and *Diagnostic Settings* via ARM template when creating a *NEW* Cosmos DB resource.

**1)** [Create a classic metric alert with a Resource Manager template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-enable-alerts-using-template)
**2)** [Automatically enable Diagnostic Settings at resource creation using a Resource Manager template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-enable-diagnostic-logs-using-template)
**3)** [Azure Cosmos DB diagnostic logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/logging)

Please Up Vote the existing entries for ARM templete functionality or create a new User Voice entry that is specific to your use case: [Azure Cosmos DB User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db?query=ARM)

Comment: my requirement is to create alerts for already existed cosmos db